# Use multiple columns for location or supertype/subtype?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Given an Equipment entity, it has a location, generically called Whereabouts.  This could be a reference to:

- a User entity (the employee who will use and be responsible for the eqipment for the next week).
- a Vendor entity (if the equpment is getting serviced).
- a StorageLocation entity (if the equpment is put away).

The piece of equpment can only be in one place at a time, even if that place is not a physical location.

Is it better:

- to have Equipment with three columns (UserId, VendorId, StorageLocationId) such that one of these columns must be not null while the other two must be null (enforced by a constraint)?
- or to have Equipment with a WhereaboutsId that references some type supertype table that then links to User, Vendor, and StorageLocation as subtype tables, even though they share no other common attributes?
- or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach to design is to think about the what-if's:

- How would the design need to change to add a 4th type?
- How would it need to change to store a common attribute?
- How would it need to change to store an attribute for only *one* of the types?

I think after going through the process of answering the questions above for the proposed designs, it will be obvious that using a supertype/subtype structure is definitely the way to go (I dare say this is a best-practice for the situation).

There are things to be concerned about, of course -- for example, ensuring that for a given supertype, a matching record must exist in exactly 1 subtype table. With a well-written stored procedure to do "transfers" between types (which is something I assume you'll need), this should be pretty straightforward to implement.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent feedback.  It was the supertype/subtype that we used but I have been guilty of over-engineering on occasion and wanted a second opinion.